# BUILD FAILED in 9s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I work on VScode Flutter project with bloc i was working normally and restart the application and then an error shows up to me in the DEBUGCONSOLE saying 'Error: Not found: 'dart:js''

[image]
[image]

THIS IS MY PUBSBEC.YAML CODE

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flutter clean

Delete pubspec.lock

flutter pub get

flutter run

Please try these. Also please dont add screenshots of error or codes. Copy paste it here.

Comment: I tried it and did not work

Comment: Please remove import js

Comment: I have exactly the same issue even for freshly created projects. Did they mess something up with latest versions of flutter? It happens for both iOS and Android

Comment: how can i remove import js

Comment: i tried to run another app i did and it works so the problem is in this project only

Comment: On top in one of the import statement you see import js. Please remove it if its not used

Answer (score 1):

Try to downgrade your flutter and then upgrade again.

> flutter downgrade v2.8.0
> flutter upgrade

Comment: the solution is that i went to the terminal and write 
'Flutter upgrade '
but you have to make sure that your flutter doctor is zero issues